# Fastest way to constantly send and receive data between 2 Android phones

Tags: android, p2p, instant-messaging

What is the fastest way to constantly send and receive data between 2 Android phones?

e.g. long, lat, IM or just some number.

**not for** an always-on connection or push services. The app is running on foreground and waiting for data on both sides.

Comment: Use SMS? Oh right, that is not free. I have a gut feeling however that trying to reach to another phone over its IP will prove unreliable at best (roaming, switching between wifi/3G, firewall policies of telecom operators and ISPs) - you'll need a server if only to identify the users, and then you'd have to be able to get an open socket on the side that receives information.

Comment: Actually it depends, how you want this constant connection. Are those phones right next to each other? Then of course Bluetooth. If there is some distance between, I think the only way would be to connect to some server side app, which manages the connection between both phones.
Like Phone A is sending requests to the server every n-seconds. The Phone B does the same. The server recognized, that Phone A wants to communicate to Phone B, so he is sending something out for Phone B only.

Comment: there is distance between the phones and my question is how exactly, by which protocol and in what way. e.g. XMPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert with Android, but there is something you might try via UDP if such connections are available from the Android platform.

Assuming your devices have private ipv4 addresses, you would need a central server (with a public ipv4 address) which could tell them how their private address is being translated by their NAT.

This translated address would have to be transmitted to other devices which could start communicating with the initiating device via UDP. If there is not much communication, make sure you enable any 'keepalive' option on the UDP connections.

If all devices have public IP addresses (which I doubt), then you just need to agree on a port and open UDP connections. The peers just have to exchange their public address.

If all devices have IPv6 addresses, then you can use these as is too (once you agree on a port). Peers just need to exchange them first too.